# Datetime issues on MS access form/table

Tags: sql, ms-access, ms-access-2007, vba

I have the below code added to a form in my db which is working fine (for now :) ).

```
SQL = "SELECT top 1 tblDataEntry.[URN], " & _
"tblDataEntry.[Receipt Date], tblDataEntry.[Supplier Name], tblDataEntry.[Lock], " & _
"tblDataEntry.[Document], tblDataEntry.[Order Type], " & _
"tblDataEntry.[PO #], tblDataEntry.[Invoice Value], tblDataEntry.[Entrytime], " & _
"tblDataEntry.[Comment] " & _
"FROM tblDataEntry " & _
"WHERE (((tblDataEntry.[URN]) Is Not Null) " & _
"AND ((tblDataEntry.[Order Type]) ='PO' ) " & _
"AND ((tblDataEntry.[Lock])= False))"
```

I want to add a line to this code so I only find records that are more than 24 hours old from the time of running and keep getting stuck.

This is what i was trying:

```
"AND ((tblDataEntry.[Entrytime]) < Dateadd(dd,-1,Now()))"
```

**Note:** Entrytime is a date/time field in the table which has already been filled with the NOW function on a previous form..

I've tried all sorts of combination to add a line in to do this but nothing works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Access, `DateAdd` requires a string value as its first option.  Change yours to this ...

```sql
Dateadd("d", -1, Now())
```

However I'm uncertain you really want to subtract 1 "d" for the comparison.  If you want 24 hours instead, use this ...

```sql
Dateadd("h", -24, Now())
```

Actually, I would be tempted to handle both date values as double-precision float numbers (which they are "under the hood") and do the comparison this way ...

```sql
CDbl(de.[Entrytime]) < (CDbl(Now()) -1)
```

Try a simple query in the Access query designer.

```sql
SELECT de.*
FROM tblDataEntry AS de
WHERE
        de.[URN] Is Not Null
    AND de.[Order Type] ='PO'
    AND de.[Lock]= False
    AND CDbl(de.[Entrytime]) < (CDbl(Now()) -1)
```

Beware `CDbl` will throw an error with Null for `[Entrytime]`.  You could avoid that problem by removing `CDbl`

```sql
AND de.[Entrytime] < (Now() -1)
```

In that case, the Date/Time values will still be evaluated as double-precision floats, but without triggering an error when `[Entrytime]` is Null.

Adjust as needed, and after you get that part working, add your field selections back again.  And, since you want `SELECT TOP 1`, include an     `ORDER BY` clause.

Finally, after you have the query you want, adapt your VBA to produce the same `SELECT` statement.  Or save the query and use that named query in your VBA code.

Comment: Ok, this seems to work, however throws a Run-Time error '94' Invalid use of Null..

Comment: So then your table design allows Null for the `[Entrytime]` field?  You could exclude those rows from the query in the same manner you excluded rows where `[URN]` is Null.  Or decide whether something else should happen when `[Entrytime]` is Null ... what would that be?

Comment: Actually, you don't absolutely *need* `CDbl` to evaluate Date/Time values as double-precision floats.  I included `CDbl` because I hoped it would make the situation clear.  But it should work without error #94 if you do it this way: `de.[Entrytime] < (Now() -1)`

Comment: Hans, your a gent... I cant believe it was so simple... I just stuck the < (Now() -1) part in and it works perfectly to the minute. Top answer!

Comment: You're welcome.  In hindsight, I think suggesting `CDbl` was not as helpful as I hoped.  I added the warning about errors with Null, and included the version which worked for you.

Answer (score 1):

My guess is problem in parentheses

Try Like this

```
SELECT TOP 1 
       T.[URN],
       T.[Receipt Date], 
       T.[Supplier Name], 
       T.[Lock],
       T.[Document], 
       T.[Order Type],
       T.[PO #], 
       T.[Invoice Value], 
       T.[Entrytime], 
       T.[Comment] 
FROM tblDataEntry AS T 
WHERE T.[URN] Is Not Null  AND 
      T.[Order Type] ='PO' AND 
      T.[Lock] = False AND
      T.[Entrytime] < DateAdd(dd,-1,Now())
```

**EDIT**

```
SQL="SELECT TOP 1 T.[URN],T.[Receipt Date],T.[Supplier Name],T.[Lock],T.[Document],            T.[Order Type],T.[PO #], T.[Invoice Value], T.[Entrytime], T.[Comment] FROM tblDataEntry AS T WHERE T.[URN] Is Not Null  AND T.[Order Type] ='PO' AND T.[Lock] = False AND T.[Entrytime] < DateAdd(dd,-1,Now())"
```

Hope this help you

Comment: This returns Run-time error '3061 Too few parameters. Expected 1

Comment: @Na'te I believe this happens when the field name(s) in your sql query do not match the table field name(s), i.e. a field name in the query is wrong or perhaps the table is missing the field altogether.

Comment: @Na'te Can you please check field name?

Comment: They are all ok, I previously seen this same suggestion.. Must have checked it 100 times now :)

Comment: Try a Debug.Print before you execute the Query that will show how it is actually understood by the DB.. So you will be able to see something there..

Comment: and also make sure that query is running in Access query window